# Filter ForeignKey by Boolean value in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, foreign-keys

I have these models:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    is_provider = models.BooleanField()

class Billing(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
```

I want to limit the choices of ForeignKey to show only the clients with `is_provider=True`. Is there something like:

```
limit_choices_to = {'is_provider': True}
```

Or anything I can use to filter the ForeignKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have the exact syntax already.

```
client = models.ForeignKey(Client, limit_choices_to = {'is_provider': True})
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize it was so easy

Answer (score 1):

Do you have tried the following:

```
limit_choices_to = {'client__is_provider': True}
```

Comment: If only I could set two answers.. Anyway, thanks for the answer :)